# Overleaf no longer compiles my bibliography file

Tags: bibliographies, citing, overleaf

I work with "Overleaf", the online Latex editor. I was writing my thesis, working with a specific documentclass of my school and everything was fine and suddenly it no longer compiles my bibliography.bib file. The citations have changed to "?" and the list of references is gone. I was only editing my tex file but nothing related to the references. For me it's much more appropriate if I can continue with Overleaf.
I can still compile with TexMaker. 
Any idea what might have gone wrong?

```
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\begin{Body}
\chapter{Introduction}
this is the reference \cite{something}
\chapter{Literature Survey}
\end{Body}
\begin{EndMatter}
\references% Generates the bibliography page
\end{EndMatter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried to recompile from scratch ?

Comment: Yes, of course, many times.

Comment: Check the log-files (.log and blg) at overleaf.

Comment: If you're still having problems, feel free to contact us at support@overleaf.com with the specifics.

Comment: Log file says there are undefined references even though I have a .bib bibliography which overleaf stopped recognizing it all of the sudden, for an unknown reason.

Comment: @LianTzeLim, I have sent a message few days ago and haven't got a response yet.

Comment: @Elnaz That's odd -- I just checked and it seems we didn't receive your message, sorry about that! Would you mind sending it again, or by using the contact form at https://www.overleaf.com/contact ?

Comment: @LianTzeLim, I remember i received a confirmation email then. I just sent another message through your contact link.

Comment: @LianTzeLim Any news here? If you can contribute a useful answer for others, please do so. If not, please vote to close as in the current state, none of us can answer and this would never be solved.

Comment: @Johannes_B After checking through Elnaz's projet, The `\references` command that generates the bibliograpy page was actually hardcoded to lookup a _different_ `.bib` file that he was using. Replacing that line with a usual `\bibliography` pointing to the correct file solved the problem. As this was so specific to his project, I didn't add an answer here.

Comment: I vote to close this question as unclear because it cannot be answered with the information available on this site. See comment above by Overleaf expert @LianTze.